# Setting $BASH_ENV to a script outputs entire contents of script to Jenkins console

Tags: bash, docker, jenkins, nvm

I have a need for `nvm` to run in a Docker container running as a Jenkins agent. I was able to get nvm to work in this context by setting `$BASH_ENV` to `$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh`.

This achieves the desired result in that `nvm` will work in my Jenkins pipeline, but has the odd side effect of outputting the entire contents of `nvm.sh` to the Jenkins console ***each and every time*** I start an `sh` block in the Jenkinsfile, like so:

```
10:50:31  [Pipeline] sh
10:50:32  + NVM_SCRIPT_SOURCE=/bin/bash
10:50:32  + '[' -z '' ']'
10:50:32  + export NVM_CD_FLAGS=
10:50:32  + NVM_CD_FLAGS=
10:50:32  + nvm_is_zsh
10:50:32  + '[' -n '' ']'
10:50:32  + '[' -z /home/jenkins/.nvm ']'
10:50:32  + case $NVM_DIR in
10:50:32  + unset NVM_SCRIPT_SOURCE
10:50:32  + nvm_process_parameters
10:50:32  + local NVM_AUTO_MODE
10:50:32  + NVM_AUTO_MODE=use
10:50:32  + '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
clipped for brevity...
```

Which would be output all over again if I were to use another `sh` block, which is a very strange effect that doesn't happen in any other context (e.g. running the Docker container by itself, outside of Jenkins), using `set +x` was ineffective.

I'm fairly certain it's something to do with the use of `$BASH_ENV` which is the only way I've managed to get `nvm` to work in all the contexts I need without having to manually source it each time.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

USER root

# Replace shell with bash so we can source files
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

# Set debconf to run non-interactively
RUN echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections

WORKDIR /home/jenkins
USER jenkins

RUN tfenv install && tfenv use

# Create needed directories and environment variables to allow non-interactive running
ENV NVM_DIR /home/jenkins/.nvm
RUN mkdir -p $NVM_DIR

# nvm will stop working in Jenkins if this is removed
ENV BASH_ENV $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh

ENV NODE_VERSION 20.5.1

# -  Install nvm and node (also includes npm)
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.4/install.sh | bash \
    && . $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm use default

ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH      $NVM_DIR/versions/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

**Example Jenkinsfile:**

```
pipeline{
    stages {
        stage ('Stage 1') {
            steps {
                script {
                   sh "echo hello" # nvm.sh contents output here...
                   sh "echo world" # ... and again here
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Is there any way to supress this output and stop it cluttering up my logs?

Comment: I'm curious why would you need `nvm` in your image? You only have one version of `node`, right?

Comment: Are you using `sh` or `bash` shell? Both are different. With `sh`, you cant solve your issue. Second, why do you even need `nvm`? Use a node version image from: https://hub.docker.com/_/node

Comment: @RobinThomas It's shown in the Dockerfile that we are removing `sh` and creating a symbolic link in its place to `bash` so I believe it to be running `bash`, not `sh` (despite the Jenkins wording)

@Iterokun Unfortunately, this is the infrastructure I need to work with.

Comment: @RawLamb What about my second question? Why do you even need `nvm`?

Comment: @RobinThomas That is a requirement I was given, the users of this Jenkins pipeline would like to be able to use different versions of node arbitrarily.

Comment: @RawLamb Are you saying that depending on node version that users select on Jenkins before triggering the job, the same `Dockefile` needs to be built with that particular node version?

Comment: @RobinThomas I'm saying that a requirement I was given, and need to work with, for that Docker image was for `nvm` to be installed and usable.

Comment: If the environment variable `BASH_ENV` exists, bash is executing the file named in this variable **every time** a non-interactive bash is started. This includes every bash subshell. I don't think you want to do this. `BASH_ENV` is typically used to set shell variables and options for bash scripts.

Comment: Your shared Dockerfile has several errors :/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement. I did not required BASH_ENV. This Dockerfile installs nvm inside jenkins

```bash
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts

USER root

ENV NVM_DIR /usr/local/nvm
ENV NODE_VERSION v16.17.0
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/nvm && apt-get update && echo "y" | apt-get install curl
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
RUN /bin/bash -c "source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh && nvm install $NODE_VERSION && nvm use --delete-prefix $NODE_VERSION"
ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/$NODE_VERSION/bin
ENV PATH $NODE_PATH:$PATH

USER jenkins
```

Then inside the jenkins container, nvm is ready to use

[image]

Also I tried your pipeline (fixing it)

```
pipeline{
    agent any
    stages {
        stage ('Stage 1') {
            steps {
                script {
                   sh "echo hello" 
                   sh "echo world" 
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

And no creepy echos/logs are showed

[image]